How to enable good autocompletion for python in react/monaco editor?
I have been trying to find a solution to implement richer autocompletion for python for quite some time now, and I have not been able to do it yet. I would like to achieve the same autocompletion result as javascript. I thought it should be easy, but I started to come across articles that say that you need to deploy a language server for this purpose. Is there really no simpler way to achieve autocompletion (for example, to display a list of methods for a class created by the user)? I found the following method (which, by the way, does not work quite correctly and, in addition, all the hints must be implemented manually):
import { FC, useEffect } from "react";
import * as monaco from "monaco-editor";

function createDependencyProposals(range) {
  // returning a static list of proposals, not even looking at the prefix (filtering is done by the Monaco editor),
  // here you could do a server side lookup
  return [
    {
      label: "test",
      insertText: "test",
      range: range,
    },
  ];
}

export const MonacoEditorComponent: FC = () => {
  let flag = false;
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!flag) {
      monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider("python", {
        provideCompletionItems: function (model, position) {
          const word = model.getWordUntilPosition(position);
          const range = {
            startLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
            endLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
            startColumn: word.startColumn,
            endColumn: word.endColumn,
          };
          return {
            suggestions: createDependencyProposals(range),
          };
        },
      });

      monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
        value: "def something():\n\treturn 5\n\n",
        language: "python",
      });
    }

    flag = true;
  }, []);
  return <div id="container" style={{ width: 800, height: 400 }}></div>;
};

